# Call GWT Method from Handwritten JavaScript

Tags: javascript, gwt, jsni

I'd like to execute some js method from browser console to call gwt code. For ex.

> showMyWindow();

js:

```
function showMyWindow() {
// call gwt code from here MyWindow::showMe()
}
```

gwt:

```
class MyWindow extends Window {
  public static showMe {
    MyWindow wnd = new MyWindow();
    wnd.show();
  }
}
```

How to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As outlined in the [JSNI documentation on calling GWT Java from handwritten Javascript](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#calling), you need to expose the showMyWindow function so your other javascript can be called. Sometime before you want to actually call showMyWindow in JS, run a function like this.

```
public static native void exportShowMe() /*-{
  $wnd.showMyWindow = $entry(@my.package.client.MyWindow::showMe());
}-*/;
```

After you have called that, you'll be able to call `showMyWindow()` in regular JS and have your static method called.

As an aside, your `showMe` method probably needs a return type, in this case, most likely `void`.